# Can I return my own custom token base authentication in node js

Tags: node.js, rest, token, restify

I am using node-js restify. While signing a user up `server.head('/signup', function (req, res, next)` I generate a custom token.

```
token = ***
res.set('token', token);
res.send();
```

I am trying to send the token back but I can't find any documentation on how this is done. **How do I send a token in a header response?**

Comment: What do you mean by token?

Comment: @RushyPanchal token base authentication

Answer (score 1):

Check this working sample

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.head('/token', function(req, res, next){
   res.writeHead (200, {'token': Math.random()});
   res.end();
});

app.listen(3001);
```

And the POSTMAN request
[image]

As you can see everything works as expected, the response body is always empty, but header has token field